# Submit web form button - Dreamweaver

Tags: forms

I am trying to use Dreamweaver CC 2017.5 to update an existing website. I am stuck on a web form button that won't submit the information. There is both a `Submit` button (which does not work) and a `Reset` button (which does work). I have looked for a link to send the form to an email, but I haven't found it yet.

Here is the existing code, as extracted from the large form coding:

```
Comments:
<br>
<textarea rows="8" name="comments" cols="50"></textarea>
<p> 
<input id="SUBMIT" name="Submit Form" type="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
<input type="RESET" value="Reset Form" name="RESET">
</td>
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Those buttons won't work if you haven't set a form action. Here is a working example to help: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Thanks, Harley... that looks like exactly what I needed.